# Differentiating a Unique Multi-variable Function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I found this interesting property during my research were $\beta$ is some function of x and the a,e,n are all dependent on x;

If  $\frac{d \hspace{1pt} \beta(a,e,n)}{dx}=\beta(a+\phi,e,n)+\beta(a,e+\phi,n)$

Then $\frac{d^\gamma \hspace{1pt} \beta(a,e,n)}{(dx)^\gamma}=
\sum_{i=0}^\gamma\binom{i}{\gamma}\beta(a+\phi(i),e+\phi(\gamma-i),n)$

What is the name of this property? Or how could I find the name of this property?

Comment: what is the $\beta$ function in this question?

Comment: @ZachEffman $\beta$ represents any function were the if statement is true.